# How to fix image name

Tags: php

PHP code for this script is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Count total files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
$pdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$userID = $_SESSION['memberID'];
// Prepared statement
$query = "INSERT INTO images (user,post_date,name,image) VALUES('$userID','$pdate',?,?)";  
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
// Loop all files
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
// File name
$filename = explode('.',$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);  
// Get extension
$ext = strtolower(end($filename));
// Valid image extension
$valid_ext = array("png","jpeg","jpg");
if(in_array($ext, $valid_ext)){
// Upload file
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename)){  
// Execute query
$statement->execute(array($filename,'upload/'.$filename));
}    
}      
}
header('Location: view_images');
}
}
```

HTML code for this script is:

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php if(isset($errors)){
echo $errors;
}?>
<div class="profile-edit-container add-list-container">
<div class="profile-edit-header fl-wrap">
<h4>Post images</h4>
</div>
<div class="custom-form">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="act-widget fl-wrap">
<div class="act-widget-header">
<div class="add-list-media-wrap fuzone">
<div class="fu-text">
<span><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Add images</span>
</div>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="imgInput2" class="upload" multiple>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn big-btn color-bg flat-btn">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

When i upload example 3 diferent images, and every image have diferent name ( car1.jpg, car3.jpg, car4.jpg ) when i finishing upload proccess every image into database have same name ( `Array` ). That is the problem, because i want to store original image name or generate using this code `. substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).` but im stuck and i can't generate.

Comment: `$filename` is __array__.

Comment: So if i change ```$filename``` and put this code example ```. substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).``` they will generate image name into ```f13xd3145x.jpg```? @u_mulder

Comment: Instead of ```$filename``` i put ```$file_parh = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).$ext;``` and now nothing is store into database. @u_mulder

Comment: Don't concatenate data into your query.  Even though you believe that `$userID` and `$pdate` are fine, you may update your code in the future which can make them unsafe.  You're already using parameters for other things... use them for these variables too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the piece of code that you need:

```
$filename = explode('.',$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);  
// Get extension
$ext = strtolower(end($filename));
// Valid image extension
$valid_ext = array("png","jpeg","jpg");
if(in_array($ext, $valid_ext)){
    // generate a filename
    $filename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $ext;
    // Upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename)){  
        // Execute query
        $statement->execute(array($filename,'upload/'.$filename));
    }    
}
```

Comment: My friend problem is next, when i checked 3 images all images get the same name with this code. How to  fix that?

Comment: Please, do not clarify anything not related to original question in comments. Ask another question instead.

Comment: But I suppose that happens because `time()` returns same result, try to use `microtime()` instead of `time()`.